# SQL - Return entire row with the highest value of one column

Tags: sql

I have a table "profit_by_sales_rep" with data like the following:

[image]

I would like to be able to create a single SQL command that returns the first name, last name, and total profit for the user with highest total profit in the table (in other words, return a single row). I attempted the following:

```
SELECT sales_rep_first_name, sales_rep_last_name, MAX(total_profit)
FROM profit_by_sales_rep 
GROUP BY sales_rep_first_name, sales_rep_last_name
```

, however that just returned what I already had.

I am pretty sure there is a fairly simple query to get the result I want. I would be grateful for ideas. Thanks

Comment: I do not see any difference between input and output...

Comment: sorry, you are correct. I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: What if there is more than one user tied for first place?

Comment: I must say I find penalizing a person for mistake in a question decidedly petty. Aren't we here to help one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to do something like this for MySQL:

```
SELECT sales_rep_first_name, sales_rep_last_name, total_profit
FROM profit_by_sales_rep 
ORDER BY total_profit desc
LIMIT 1
```

and for SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 sales_rep_first_name, sales_rep_last_name, total_profit
FROM profit_by_sales_rep 
ORDER BY total_profit desc
```

Be aware that this will return a "random" row if there are more than one user with the same `total_profit`